# Differentiate loaded objects from a file with UUIDs

Tags: c++, qt, guid, uuid

In my project, I save the data objects into a file. 
Some of the objects reference other objects, so all the objects have an UUID identifier which is also stored, in order to be able, after loading from the file, to have the same referenced object as when the project was saved.

Now we want to add the concept of "libraries". These are pretty the same as a project file, but they load the objects into an existing project, so being able to reuse them.

The problem is that the UUIDs of the objects that are inside the libraries are not unique any more, since a library can be loaded multiple times in the same project.

Are there any techniques to solve this situation?

Additional info:

All the objects are organized in a hierarchical structure.
There is a "library object", which is the parent of all the objects loaded from a library.

Hierarchy example (UUIDs simplified to just numbers):

```
Parent 1 - UUID 1
   |- Child 1 - UUID 2
   |- Child 2 - UUID 3
   |- Library 1 - UUID 4
   |     | - **OBJECTS INSIDE LIBRARY LOADED / SAVED TO LIBRARY FILE WITH THEIR UUID (NOTE THAT UUIDs ARE THE SAME AS IN NEXT LIB)
   |     | - LibChild 1 - UUID 10
   |     | - LibChild 2 - UUID 11
   |     | - LibChild 3 - UUID 12 References UUID 10
   |- Library 2 - UUID 5
         |
         | - **OBJECTS INSIDE LIBRARY LOADED / SAVED TO LIBRARY FILE WITH THEIR UUID (NOTE THAT UUIDs ARE THE SAME AS IN PREV LIB)
         | - LibChild 1 - UUID 10
         | - LibChild 2 - UUID 11
         | - LibChild 3 - UUID 12 References UUID 10
```

In the example, note that LibChild 3 inside the library references LibChild 1 of the same library. Since both LibChild 1 have the same UUID, the second library instance references the incorrect object.

Also note that the hierarchy can be changed by the user at any time, so if a context is needed (as told in a comment), I would prefer not to depend on the parent objects.

Comment: They are either the same, so you need to make a sharing/reference mechanism, or they are different, so you need to put them into a context. What is the actual problem with having two UUIDs the same?

Comment: @luk32 The objects are different, I want to reference the object inside the correct library instance (see my last update) As you state, I may need to put them into a context, but how? Please, note that the hierarchy can be changed by the user, so I would rather prefer not to depend on the parent items